# What is the purpose of Thévenin's theorem on equivalent circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electrical-engineering

What is the purpose of Thévenin's theorem use if there are multiple formulas and theorems available for solving a circuit like KVL, mesh, nodal, etc?

Comment: More of a question for [electronics.se]

Comment: This question appears to be mostly an excuse to link to your website. I've removed the link- please do not repost it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to simplifying circuit analysis when variable loads are involved, Thevenin's theorem complements the maximum power transfer theorem which states the maximum power is delivered to a load connected to two terminals that matches the source impedance looking into the two terminals. This is referred to as impedance matching. The source impedance is the Thevenin impedance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually, max pwr transfer is when load Z is complex conjugate if thev Z

Comment: @relayman357 Yes I know. I didn't want to go into the details of the impedance matching,  and I didn't want to say only matching resistance since it isn't limited to resistance. I guess I can't please everyone.

Comment: The concept of "source impedance" appears and makes sense due to Thevenin's theorem.

Comment: Hi @BobD, sorry friend.  Not trying to be hypercritical.  Just figured OP could understand "conjugate" if he could handle complex impedance.  I understand your motivation to keep it simpler.  thank you sir

Comment: @relayman357 No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thevenin's theorem allows any single-port linear network to be reduced to a single voltage source and a single impedance in series with the voltage source, thereby simplifying the network for evaluation. (Norton's theorem allows any single-port linear network to be reduced to a single current source and a single impedance in parallel with the current source, thereby simplifying the network for evaluation.)  The Thevenin equivalent circuit is valid only over the linear range for the actual circuit.  Some applications of the Thevenin equivalent circuit are: (1) To determine change in load voltage; that is, too predict range of load voltage variation due to change in load resistance, (b) to determine the maximum power that can be transferred to a load from the network. For a simple introduction see [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317488825_Thevenin's_Theorem_and_its_Applications](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317488825_Thevenin%27s_Theorem_and_its_Applications) on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Thevenin's theorem is not (only) about solve a circuit.

Thevenin's theorem states a fundamental fact about linear circuits: when seen from outside as a two pins element, they are always equivalent to a power source with an impedance.

This equivalence is what allows to talk about the load connected to something (no matter of its structure), the output impedance of a power source (no matter power source kind) and its output voltage when no load, ...

Answer (score -1):

Like the method of Images of charge in electrostatics that ease the problem of solving the differential equation that has to be solved.
Thevenin theorem in same way is a technique that can be used to solve complex circuits where normal approach turns out to be difficult. Like the method of images it is also a technique to visualize the solution to the multiple equations formed by following a certain number of steps.

Comment: Thevenin's theorem is not a technique is, recall its usual name, a theorem. It holds some statements and proof them. Latter, these statements have some applications including the ones in circuits analysis.

Comment: How did we get those techniques then?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui They were first proved and later a certain steps were defined for its application